# Download from URL into GCP bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Given a URL that points to a large file, is there a shortcut to getting that file into a bucket, without downloading it locally and then uploading?

Is there a simpler way to do it, other than building a docker image that does the task and run that in GCP somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52768643/15774176)

> **1:** **You can do it  using curl command by streaming the data directly into the bucket.**

```
curl http://speedtest.tele2.net/10GB.zip | gsutil cp -gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/10GB.zip
```

> **2:** **Files smaller than 4.6 GB.**
>
> Original approach: This works as long as your download is less than ~
> 4.6 GB. Launch the Cloud Shell (first icon on your top right after you login to your project in GCP) and use wget to download the file you
> want. For instance, to download 7-Zip type: wget
> https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1805-x64.exe Now with the file in your Cloud
> Shell user home you can copy it to a Google Cloud Storage bucket using
> the gsutil command:

```
gsutil cp ./7z1805-x64.exe gs://your_bucket_name/
```

> **3:** **Files bigger than 4.6 GB.**
>
> Create a directory in your Cloud Shell user home `mkdir ~/mybucket`

> Now mount your bucket in that directory using gcsfuse:

```
gcsfuse bucket_name ~/mybucket
```

> Change the current directory to mount point directory: `cd mybucket` (if you want to run "df -h ." to see how much space you got
> in that mount point) Now use wget to get the file directly into your
> bucket (sample using 10GB file off the web):

```
wget https://speed.hetzner.de/10GB.bin
```

For more information, you can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/) on storage transfer services and creating a [URL list](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-url-list).

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage does not provide the ability to load an object from a URL.

You must write your own code, use the CLI or a managed service such as [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer-service)